# Symbols no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Após criamos um modelo no rails é possível alterar o symbol criado?

Por exemplo criei um modelo chamado transação, o rails cria no plural transaçãos mas gostaria de alterar esse nome  para transações é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alterando o arquivo config/initializers/inflections.rb é possível configurar a  pluralização no Rails.
Recomendo dar uma lida na apostila da Caelum para melhor entender.

[Apostila ruby on rails - caelum](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-ruby-on-rails/active-record/#7-16-pluralizacao-com-inflections)

Answer (score 1):

É possível você configurar o plural como precisar, alterando o arquivo `config/initializers/inflections.rb`, que irá refletir em toda sua aplicação.
Vale lembrar, que o Rails é um framework CoC (Convention over configuration), sendo que a convenção é que o código seja escrito em inglês.
Isso significa que quanto mais você codar fora da convenção, mais configurações terá que fazer para obter o mesmo resultado esperado ao final.